# How to get rid of whitespace without excessive comments?

Tags: html, css, whitespace

Here is a code snippet from my page:

```
<input value="Search" type="submit" /><!-- whitespace
--><span class="vdivider"></span><!-- whitespace
--></form><!-- whitespace
--><form action="login_action.php" method="post"><!-- whitespace
--><?php
```

Those whitespace comments are to get rid of the whitespace on each side of the divider. Is this really the only way of doing this? There has to be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Could just put the markup on the same line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option to consider - use a templating engine if you can. For example, in [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), there's a [{strip}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.strip.tpl) function that does exactly this:

```
{* the following will be all run into one line upon output *}
{strip}
<table border='0'>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <a href="{$url}">
    <font color="red">This is a test</font>
   </a>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
{/strip}
```

Output:

```
<table border='0'><tr><td><a href="http://. snipped...</a></td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `font-size:0` hack. Basically, you set `font-size:0` on the parent element, and set the font-size explicitly on the children.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/mLZYW/1/

(Presentation without hack: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/mLZYW/)

Answer (score 2):

White-space only shows when it is around or next to inline elements, so at least for the forms you don´t need it (if you haven´t set your forms to `display:inline`...).

Positioning or floating things almost always removes the unwanted white-spaces, so for example if your `.vdivider` is supposed to be a vertical divider / new line, you can just use `display:block` on the `input` before it and remove that element and the comments around it.

Comment: I did, actually, because I have two forms next to each other (search and register/login) and they are on the same line.

Comment: @John Smith That explains it then :-) By the way, I can't remember the last time I had problems with white-spaces, I guess I tend to float elements when I want them next to each other and that's what I'd probably do in your case as well. Depending on your browser needs, you can also use things like `display:inline-block`.

Answer (score 2):

Whitespace between elements (including newlines and tabs) cause browsers to insert spaces where there should be none.

The most elegant method that I've seen used to get around this issue is putting the `>` on the next line, instead of on the same line.  This way, it's still legal html, and you can still keep it pretty.

For example:

```
<input value="Search" type="submit" />
    <span class="vdivider"></span>
    </form><form action="login_action.php" method="post">
    <?php>
```

would become:

```
<input value="Search" type="submit" 
    /><span class="vdivider"></span
    ></form><form action="login_action.php" method="post"
    ><?php>
```